# apache server installing

Tags: apache-2.2

when i have installed apacher and run http://localhost i get following screenshot http://i35.tinypic.com/34j5d9s.png it means that everyithng is fine and apache works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have IIS installed on the machine. If you want Apache to run on port 80, you'll need to either remove IIS, or disable it's default website (in the IIS Management Console, select the default website and click Stop).

When Apache is working, you'll get:
[image]
<sub>(source: [ibm.com](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-db2mblog3/fig04.jpg))</sub>

Comment: thanks and can you tell me how disable it i am new in  servers and dont know exactly

Comment: Start -> All Programs-> Administrative Tools -> Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager. In the Connections pane (left) expand your computer, Sites, find Default Web Site. Right click it -> Edit Binding -> Select the line(s) with Port 80; Remove button. Restart Apache.